# Visual Studio Code - Debug Angular 2 against specific environment

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm new in Angular, i'm trying debug code in Visual Studio code. For debug i'm use extension Debugger for Chrome, with this configuration:

```
**launch.json**
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [       
      {
        "name": "ng serve",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"                                    
      },
      {
        "name": "ng test",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
      },
      {
        "name": "ng e2e",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
        "protocol": "inspector",
        "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.js"]
      }      
    ]
  }
```

It works fine. But i have a problem with environments. I have 3 different environments. In environemnt.ts i have route to localhost, and next two are api on server, for example environemnt.tst1.ts and environemnt.tst2.ts.

If i want to exec against some envrionment by angular cli, it's ok. I write ng serve --env=ts and working against environment ts1. But if i want to debug. I must write npm start (it is condition for debug mode) and it generate following code :

```
npm start

> web-client@0.0.0 start C:\GitProjects\web-client
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

But it working against basic environment.ts

And my question is, how i can choose agaist another environment. I'm trying f.e. some add param `env` with value ts1 to config file, but it wrote's mi, Property env is not allowed.

Do you have experience with this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i think, so i must set it in config debugger, but i set it in package.json. Add param env=tst1.

```
{
  "name": "web-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --env=tst1",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
....
```